# Delete variable within variable

Tags: python, variables, namespaces

I am looking to understand some basic python functions in their entirety.  How does the "del" produce this (in bash):

```
>>> temp = 1
>>> python = 1 + temp
>>> 
>>> 
>>> temp
1
>>> 
>>> python
2
>>> 
>>> 
>>> del temp
>>> 
>>> 
>>> python
2
>>> 
>>> temp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'temp' is not defined
>>> 
>>> 
>>>
```

Comment: Are you asking how variables are deleted, or is there some other behaviour here that is unexpected?

Comment: `python` was already assigned the value `2`.  It doesn't make a _reference_ to `temp` in order to produce the result.  What's unexpected here?

Comment: see answer from Elias Benevedes below.  I didn't understand that variables are defined at one point in time, and not continuously redefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way variables are created are in reference one time to another variable. In your example, python = temp + 1, python is equal to temp plus 1 **at its time of definition.**.  The variable python does not re-compute every time the processor goes through a loop. Its value is only defined once. If a variable included in its definition changes, it does not change.

Comment: Thanks, Elias - you've entirely explained what I misunderstood about defining variables in this example.

Answer (score 1):

For del in python, it means

```
Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace
```

so when you del var, it removes this variable, and it's not usable when you call it again, that's why exception happens.

Comment: Thanks - I was asking why the var 'python' will run without a NameError, after deleting 'temp', seemingly contained within var 'python'.

Answer (score 0):

> python delete variable within variable

`temp` is not inside `python`. In the line

```
python = 1 + temp
```

only the *value* of `temp` will be used to create the variable `python`. So if you delete `temp`, it won't affect `python`.

Comment: Thanks - you've understood and explained well.

Answer (score 0):

[**Here**](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) is the what the manual for the python del command says:

> Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or
>   global namespace, depending on whether the name occurs in a global
>   statement in the same code block. If the name is unbound, a NameError
>   exception will be raised.